# Saving PDF from tcpdf to Database

Tags: php, file-upload, phpmyadmin, tcpdf

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
  $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","courier_system");
  $uname='Honey';
  $con_id=2;
    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
    $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
    $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Consignment Receipt");  
    $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
    $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
    $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
    $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
    $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
    $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
    $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
    $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
    $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
    $obj_pdf->SetFont('times', '', 14);  
    $obj_pdf->AddPage();
    $cotent='
    <div style="text-align:right;">
    <img width="100px" height="70px" src="images/logo.jpeg"></img>
        <h1 align="centre" style="color:blue;">Receipt</h1>
        <br/></div>
        <hr size="5px">';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $cotent='<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <th width="50%">Order Date</th>
                  <th width="50%">Order ID</th>
                </tr>';
    $cotent.=fetch_data($uname,$cid);
    $cotent.='</table>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "courier_system");  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM consignment where user_name='$uname' and con_id=$cid";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $id=$row['branch_sou_id'];
    $cotent='<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <th width="50%">Branch Address:</th>
                </tr>';
    $cotent.=fetch_data1($id);
    $cotent.='</table><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $cotent='<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <th width="50%">From:</th>
                  <th width="50%">To:</th>
                </tr>';
    $cotent.=fetch_data2($uname,$cid);
    $cotent.='</table><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $obj_pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
    $cotent='
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">Sou Pincode</th>
                <th width="10%">Des Pincode</th>
                <th width="13%">Pickup Date</th>
                <th width="10%">Weight</th>
                <th width="10%">Mode</th>
                <th width="12%">Texable Value</th>
                <th width="14%">IGST</th>
                <th width="20%">Total</th>
            </tr>';
    $cotent.=fetch_data3($uname,$cid);
    $cotent.='</table><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $obj_pdf->SetFont('times', '', 14);
    $tax=0.12*$row['price'];
    $total=floor(0.5+$tax+$row['price']);
    $cotent='Total Price is Rs.'. $total;
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $cotent='The Price in Word '. getIndianCurrency($tax+$row['price']);
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $cotent='
    <div style="text-align:right;">
    <p style="font-size:16px">Signature</p>
    <img width="100px" height="70px" src="images/Signa.jpg"></img>
        </div>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($cotent);
    $content=$obj_pdf->Output('', 'S');    
    //header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    //header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=pdf.pdf");
    //header("Location:abc.php?str='$sontent'");
    echo $content."<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
    // $data=file_get_contents('pdf.pdf');
    // echo $data;
    $sql="update consignment set receipt='$content' where con_id=4";
    if(mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
    {
      echo "hiiii";
    }
    else {
      echo "Error";
      echo mysqli_error($connect);
    }
```

The Photo of Error[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCT1U.png)

When I run then it will upload pdf file in the database.
I am using PHPmyadmin database.
In this code, the Invoice are generated and this pdf I want to upload in the database for the further use.
But the error are generated from the Query that I am using.
This PDF is generated using the TCPDF.
In this, the detail are the come from the database at the run time using the PHP code.
Thank You.
[Please Refer this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529605/php-mysql-saving-pdf-to-database)

Comment: Trying to insert what essentially is binary data as a string literal is a Bad Idea. Storing what seems to be order data inflated to a PDF via HTML in a data base looks even more questionable than putting it into a [DMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system).

Comment: How to convert tcpdf pdf to binary data using PHP coding.

Comment: Please refer to [How to insert blob into MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31115776). Using [`$obj_pdf->Output('', 'S')`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/) you should get the PDF data - the is nothing to `convert`. I don't know of any `PHPmyadmin database` - from the tag description, I glean that there is a MySQL database.